# Failed to create keystore

Tags: flutter, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

It was working fine, but I encountered a surprising problem, which is the loss of the storage key, and it does not even show sha1 and the rest of the keys
I think I updated one of the tools
In your opinion, what is the solution

## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oelFo.png)

I tried deleting the gridl file and the Android file, and I even tried deleting Android Studio, but it didn't work